# charset on REST API.. æøå

Tags: php, json, api

How to make æøå work in a response from a REST API?

The response is generated with json_encode() and since the input array must be utf8-encoded the special chars are not readable in the response..

I have tried to set the charset in the content-type header, but still the same!?

```
Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
```

The special chars as æøå are still not readable!?

## response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 04 Jul 2011 16:16:16 GMT
Server: Apache
Content-Length: 91
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/json

{"result":[{"id":9,"name":"hehe \u00e6\u00f8\u00e5","type":0,"vatcode_id":0,"account":10}]}
```

Comment: Are you able to parse the data via utf8_encode() before parsing the code to json? I have used this with non-utf8 characters in the past and in some instances it worked very well. It's not the best case scenario but if it works for you great.

Comment: @Ryan The characters are correctly encoded `\u00e6` represents `æ`, for instance.

Comment: @Artefacto I understood, I deal with non-utf8 characters daily and even when a variety of non-utf8 characters are encoded properly you can still parse utf8_encode() that allows correct display once pasrsed via json_encode().

Comment: Use this library, it converts malformed JSON to well-formed JSON.: [php JSON](https://code.google.com/p/php-json/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything seems OK in your response. Control characters or non-ASCII characters are encoded by `json_encode` in the form `\uXXXX`. There's nothing wrong with that and the client should be able to understand those escape sequences.

There's also not much you can do about it, unless you want to post-process the output of `json_encode`.